# Symfony 2 - doctrine:mapping:import to custom namespace

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm just getting started with Symfony2, currently trying to generate Doctrine entities from an existing database. I'm following the [official tutorial on the topic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), however, I'd like to have my entities generated in a different namespace other than the default (`MyVendor\MyBundle\Model\Entity` instead of `MyVendor\MyBundle\Entity`).

I've edited the `config.yml` file like this:

```
doctrine:
   orm:
     entity_managers:
       default:
         mappings:
           MyBundle:
             prefix: MyVendor\MyBundle\Model\Entity
             dir: Model/Entity
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work, as entities are still generated in the default namespace and directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change above code as following: Make auto_mapping true...

orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default

```
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings: ~
```

Try this.. Hope this will work for you.